# Maximal Sets Under a Hereditary Property

Tags: algorithm

I have a set S and a boolean valued function f on the subsets of S. The function f has the "hereditary property": if f(A) is true and B is a subset of A, then f(B) is true.

Is there an algorithm that finds the maximal subsets of S under which f evaluates to true? A set A is maximal in the sense that f(A) is true, but if B contains A and is larger than A, then f(B) is false.

Comment: Do you know the representation of f? Is this homework?

Comment: I'm stuck on a small research project. f is given as follows: If S is a set of boolean variable, then f is the solvability of a CNF expression restricted to those variables.

Comment: Does the reverse apply - that is, if f(E) is true for all E that are subsets of A, then f(A) must be true?
Or might there be some set A {B,C} where f(B) and f(C) are true, but f(A) is false?

Comment: Kevin, the reverse is not true.

Comment: @wye.bee "CNF expression restricted to those variables" Is this a monotone formula (= no negative literals)? Otherwise, please explain in more detail.

Comment: @Per The CNF might have negative literals. Given a CNF C, there is a set of variables that are used in C, call it S. Let A be a subset of S. Define the restriction of C to A as the CNF which contains every clause in C which only contains variables from the subset A.

For example the restriction of ((a || !b) && (!a || c) && (!b)) to {a, b} is ((a || !b) && (!b)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backtracking. Pseudocode:

```
def A(c,r,u):
    # c - current set
    # r - remaining elements
    # u - unused, forbidden elements
    if r == []:
        for i in u:
            if f(c + [i]):   # Check if c is really maximal
               return
        print c
    else:
        x = r[0]
        r' = r without first element
        if f(c + [x]):
            A(c + [x], r', u)
        A(c, r', u + [x])
```

Run A([], [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n], [])

This has exponential complexity, and you can't avoid it, for example if f(A) = does A have at most n/2 elements, there are exponentially many maximal sets. You need to assume something more about f to get a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Hereditary property lets you do nice pruning of the search space. Create an ordering on elements, if there is not one already. Then, only create sets which have elements sorted.

Start with one-element sets - find ones which satisfy...(1)

Then create all two element sets - for each one element set, try to append all sets from (1) which are larger...(2) Important: remember their relations: for sets {s} and {b} (s < b) from (1) if {s,b} is in (2), remember {s,b}.tail as {b} and add {s,b} to collection {s}.offspring.

Now just go up in number of elements. Call (2) "old" and begin creating "new". For every s in old, try append every t in s.tail.offspring, forming set with one more element. If is satisfies, add it to "new", set its .tail (to t) and it to s.offspring. Thus you get all satisfying 3-elements. (to optimize you can now forget all .tails from "old" and let gc get rid of previous generation) Repeat to get 4-elements from 3-elements etc.

Maximal sets are those that wasn't successful while being s and also has empty .offspring.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating f means testing the satisfiability of a CNF formula. I would be inclined to integrate the search for maximal sets with a SAT solver.

Starting from a [DPLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) base, make the following modifications.

1. In addition to being *true* or *false*, a variable can be *removed*. When DPLL selects a variable to branch on, the branch goes three ways.
2. Unit propagation is the same.
3. Pure literal elimination doesn't work now. However, we can do a two-way branch on the pure variable (useful truth value or removed) instead of a three-way.
4. Check incrementally whether, for each assigned variable, there is a clause satisfied only by that assignment. If not, prune – this subtree contains no maximal solutions.
5. If the partial assignment satisfies all of the clauses, then add the set of removed and unassigned variables to the output. There may be duplicates.